# why $_SESSION not unique and looks duplicated

Tags: php, session

I've created 2 different directories on my website as follow

```
my_site.com/boo
```

and

```
my_site.com/koo
```

and i've uploaded in both the following test script (3 files)

1.php // Input form

```
<?PHP
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
?>
<form method="post" action="2.php">
<input name="loginid" type="text" id="loginid">
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

2.php // check if login it correct (send me to 3.php) if not then back to 1.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$loginid=$_POST['loginid'];
if ($loginid="okay") {
$_SESSION['loginid'] = "logged";
header("Location: 3.php ");
exit;
} else {
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Wrong";
header("Location: 1.php ");
exit;
}
?>
```

3.php // it should gives Hello to admin if logged correct.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loginid']) {
echo "Hello To Admin";
} else {
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Please Login";
header("Location: 1.php ");
exit;
}
?>
```

**Now my problem**

If i went to `my_site.com/boo/1.php` and logged correct 
then once i go to `my_site.com/koo/3.php` it gives me message `Hello to admin` as if i'm logged and this means if i've 2 different scripts on 2 different directories on my website using the same php skeleton so i can be logged to both !! why not unique.

it will hurts me as if i've identical scripts on my website with different directories and i don't indeed want to give access to all :)

i've an idea but not sure if correct or not so please advice.

i'll add check file (2.php) random code

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$loginid=$_POST['loginid'];
if ($loginid="okay") {

$random = rand(1, 1000000);
$_SESSION['loginid'] = "".$random.""; // random

header("Location: 3.php ");
exit;
} else {
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Wrong";
header("Location: 1.php ");
exit;
}
?>
```

so any help
~ Thanks

Comment: Sessions span directories within a website, as you just discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use session_name(). This will make your $_SESSION variable to be connected to the session name instead of the global session context.

Documentation:
http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

page 1:

```
session_name('first_page');
session_start();
$_SESSION['hello'] = "hi";
```

page 2:

```
session_name('second_page');
session_start();
// will generate false
var_dump(isset($_SESSION['hello']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Session is not limited to a directory or files, it's a way of sharing data from the same user... it is meant to work this way

Answer (score 2):

Session ID is sent using cookie.

Cookie is based on domain name, as your sites sits on same domain, they also share PHPSESSID cookie.

When starting session try to name it first using http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Read this for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_name()` to make unique sessions:

/koo:

```
session_name('koo');

session_start();
```

/foo:

```
session_name('foo');

session_start();
```